# sorting array in bash and regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I have an array that have the CPU core num and a number for each core.
the array is totals.

How can I sort

```
totals=( CPU0=12345 CPU1=23456 CPU3=01234)
```

according to numbers and return the sorted version of cpu number for example (3,0,1) means it is sorted and core 3 is the min and core 1 is the max, in bash? and then assign (3,0,1) to an array?

Comment: Don't you think it would be easier if you just asked us how to write the whole script rather than letting us write it step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for sorting:

```
echo ${totals[*]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n -t= -k2
```

To store only the CPU numbers in a new array, try:

```
sorted_cpu_numbers=( $(echo ${totals[*]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n -t= -k2 | awk -F= '{print substr($1, 4, length($1))}') )
```